# Angular - Add custom compoment inside nav content

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap navs and I would like to set a custom component as nav content.

navs.component.html

```
<div class="col-12">
<ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="active" class="nav-tabs">
    <li [ngbNavItem]="1">
        <a ngbNavLink>Nav 1</a>
      <ng-template ngbNavContent>
          <app-custom-component ngbNavContent class=""></app-custom-component>
      </ng-template>
        

    </li>
    <li [ngbNavItem]="2">
        <a ngbNavLink>Nav 2</a>
        <ng-template ngbNavContent>
            <p>
                Exercitation +1 labore velit, blog sartorial PBR leggings next level wes anderson artisan four loko
                farm-to-table craft beer twee. Qui photo booth letterpress, commodo enim craft beer mlkshk aliquip jean shorts
                ullamco ad vinyl cillum PBR. Homo nostrud organic, assumenda labore aesthetic magna delectus mollit. Keytar
                helvetica VHS salvia yr, vero magna velit sapiente labore stumptown. Vegan fanny pack odio cillum wes anderson
                8-bit, sustainable jean shorts beard ut DIY ethical culpa terry richardson biodiesel. Art party scenester
                stumptown, tumblr butcher vero sint qui sapiente accusamus tattooed echo park.
            </p>
        </ng-template>
    </li>
    <li [ngbNavItem]="3">
        <a ngbNavLink>Nav 3</a>
        <ng-template ngbNavContent>
            <p>
                Sed commodo, leo at suscipit dictum, quam est porttitor sapien, eget sodales nibh elit id diam. Nulla facilisi.
                Donec egestas ligula vitae odio interdum aliquet. Duis lectus turpis, luctus eget tincidunt eu, congue et odio.
                Duis pharetra et nisl at faucibus. Quisque luctus pulvinar arcu, et molestie lectus ultrices et. Sed diam urna,
                egestas ut ipsum vel, volutpat volutpat neque. Praesent fringilla tortor arcu. Vivamus faucibus nisl enim, nec
                tristique ipsum euismod facilisis. Morbi ut bibendum est, eu tincidunt odio. Orci varius natoque penatibus et
                magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris aliquet odio ac lorem aliquet ultricies in eget
                neque. Phasellus nec tortor vel tellus pulvinar feugiat.
            </p>
        </ng-template>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>


<div [ngbNavOutlet]="nav" class="mt-2">
</div>
```

My custom component (app-custom-component) would have also input and output properties. Is it possible to achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: Yes, It's possible to implement. I have already done this. What's your question ?

Comment: The code I have tried above does not work. Nothing is rendered inside nav 1 content.

Comment: remove the `ngbNavContent` from the line `<app-custom-component ngbNavContent class="">`, must be work (And don't forget import and declare the component in the module), see a fool e.g. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qgrzp?file=src/app/nav-basic.html